# How to move document library sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

We have one client requirement to move document library from one subsite to another.
While moving we should move all documents along with all the custom columns with its values as it is.
All the column value must remain same eg column name Modified By should contain same name after moving also.
in short like cut-paste
How we can do this?

Thanks,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 3):

Try [Sharepoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Synchronisation Studio http://www.simego.com/Products/Data-Synchronisation-Studio
You will need to use the extra add-in to keep the modified dates the same

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool that allows you to copy all the properties from one list to another. It's called Sharegate (www.share-gate.com). There's a free trial that only limits the number of items that you can copy. The full version of the software is sold at 375$ which is a no brainer for most of the company. Hopefully, this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

definitely saving as a template and check the box to save all content, then going to the new site and upload the template@@ I hard somewhere that could be done in explorer view but...never tried this approach...

Answer (score -1):

You can save the list as a template and check the box to 'include content'.  Then just copy over the template and create a new doc. lib. using it.  It will have all of the documents as well as the same columns, values for those columns, etc.

Comment: This may not work if there is too much data in library

Comment: That's true.  @Rushikesh, how much data is in the document library?

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply..It may have more than 600 documents in it

Comment: @Rushikesh 600 isn't too many, so that wouldn't be a problem.  What's the total size of all of the files together?  Is it a few hundred megs, a few gigs, more?  You could have 600 files each of one gig, or they could be small text files of a few KB.